# Automatically Extract URL Component From Each Request

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm using Java EE. Every time the user makes a request to the server, the URL will contain the user's userId. For example, the URL might be

\http://myApp.com/path-to-resource/?userId=1

A very large number of methods I'm writing will need access to the userId param. I could modify my code so that every single one of these methods has an extra parameter annotated with @QueryParam(userId) String userId, but it seems a bit redundant and sloppy.

What I was hoping for was a class called something like UserIdProvider which would have a method called getUserId. My Resource classes would have an instance of this class, and then getUserId would access the current request and return its userId param.

Is this possible? I thought it might have something to do with the @RequestScoped annotation, but I wasn't able to really understand how to go about implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is to make a servlet filter which extracts the userId and makes it a named Guice property.

```
public class ServletStuff extends ServletModule {
    protected Filter createUserIdScopingFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override public void doFilter(
                    ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
                HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                String userId = httpRequest.getParameter("userId");
                httpRequest.setAttribute(
                        Key.get(String.class, Names.named("userId")).toString(),
                        userId);
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }

            @Override public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

            @Override public void destroy() { }
        };
    }

    @Override protected void configureServlets() {
        filter("*").through(createUserIdScopingFilter());
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("userId") @RequestScoped
    String provideUserId() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("user id must be manually seeded");
    }
}
```

Then in my resources, I'm able to inject a provider which gives me the userId.

```
private final Provider<String> userIdProvider;

    @Inject
    public ProfileResource(@Named("userId") Provider<String> userIdProvider) {
        this.userIdProvider = userIdProvider;
    }
```

which allows me to access the current userId by just calling `userIdProvider.get()`.

I think this solution is one step more convoluted than is usually necessary, as I'm using Guice for dependency injection which fights with the standard dependency injecter for jersey/restful java, but it's working well!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter to extract this information and expose it, for example, as a CDI bean, which would be available for injection.

Alternatively, depending on your needs, simply use `@QueryParam` in a field of a resource class:

```
@QueryParam("userId")
private Long userId;
```

Comment: Thanks! The second approach might work well for me for some cases. Could you explain the first approach a bit more? I don't exactly know what that would look like.